# Duplicates in history file even after HISTCONTROL specified

Tags: bash, command-history

I am using cygwin with bash (on Windows 7 pro). I have the following in `.bashrc`:

```
# Don't put duplicate lines in the history.
export HISTCONTROL="ignoredups"
```

and the following in `.bash_profile`:

```
# source the system wide bashrc if it exists
if [ -e /etc/bash.bashrc ] ; then
    source /etc/bash.bashrc
fi

# source the users bashrc if it exists
if [ -e "${HOME}/.bashrc" ] ; then
    source "${HOME}/.bashrc"
fi
```

Yet the command history is littered with duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ignoredups` only prevents duplicates matching the preceding line. So, your history shouldn't contain

```
ls
ls
```

But it can still contain

```
ls
cd
ls
```

`man bash` says (emphasis mine):

> A value of `ignoredups` causes lines matching the **previous** history entry to not be saved.